# Canssandra replication within different data centers

Tags: cassandra

Currently, we are facing a problem, suppose that we have GCP and Azure as our cloud solution, we want to set up the cassandra cluster like this,

1. 3 nodes on GCP as the cluster, data is stored by setting replicators
2. 1 node on Azure(only hot copy) to keep all data for 3 nodes on GCP.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible declaring them as two different datacenters. Cassandra allows  you to have different replication factors depending on the DC used:

```
 replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'gcp1': 3, 'azure1': 1};
```

This is a use case similar to the one explained [here](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2012/11/multi-datacenter-replication-cassandra)

There are gotchas, first, you need to ensure that the communication between the datacenters can be established; as the traffic will go through the internet, it will be highly recommendable that SSL encryption is enabled for the communication between datacenters.

The `gcp1` datacenter should be set to use the GoogleCloudSnitch snitch, the definition of the topology is done in `cassandra-rackdc.properties`.

For the `azure1` datacenter in Azure can be tricky as it should run in virtual machines, you can find a way to set this up [here](http://blog.z-proj.com/setting-up-a-cassandra-cluster-on-azure/), note that the snitch in this DC will be `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`, and the topology is defined in `cassandra-topology.properties`.

The instructions of how to add the second datacenter can be found [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html).